# Trying to display from mySQL using a class in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm beginning php/MySql and have been asked to use a class to access my database. I can get the display to work when I have all my code in one file but when I try to call the class from another file, I get nothing.

This is the one that works:

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'testdb';

$myNewConnection = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
$query = "SELECT user_name FROM users" or die ("Error..." . mysqli_error($myNewConnection));

// execute the query
$result = $myNewConnection->query($query);

// display output
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row["user_name"] . "<br>";
}

?>
```

This is my code to call the class:

```
<?php
include("users.php");

$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'testdb';

//initiate the class
$myDB = new MyDB('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdb'); 
//$myDB = new MyDB($host,$username,$password,$dbname); 
?>
```

This is my class:

```
<?php

class MyDB {

    public $query;
    public $myConnection;

    public function _construct($host,$username,$password,$dbname){

        // establish the connection
        $this->myConnection = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
    }
    public function list_users() {

        // create query to list all users
        $this->query = "SELECT user_name FROM users" or die ("Error..." . mysqli_error($this->$myNewConnection));

        // execute the query
        $result = $this->$myConnection->query($this->$query);

        // display output
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $row["user_name"] . "<br>";
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please title each block of code with what file it is in.  Its hard to tell from the information given if you may be missing an include

Comment: Is your users.php in the same folder?

Comment: Its not clear (for me) from your question if the class works or just the procedural code

Comment: If you get nothing just a white screen. There may be an error, but you might have display_errors = Off in your php.ini check to see if errors are turned on this may highlight the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line as below (remove the dollar sign from `query` and `myConnection`):

```
$result = $this->myConnection->query($this->query);
```

*Plus* you might need to call your `list_users` function using the code below (right after instantiating your class! Pass your defined variables to constructor instead of their actual values):

```
$myDB = new MyDB($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
$myDB->list_users();
```

Also constructors are written with two underscores like this:

```
public function __construct
```

Answer (score 2):

`function __construct` with two "`_`". Delete all "`$`" after "`->`":

```
<?php

class MyDB {
    public $query;
    public $myConnection;
    public function __construct($host,$username,$password,$dbname){     
        $this->myConnection = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
    }
    public function list_users() {
        $this->query = "SELECT user_name FROM users";
        if($result = $this->myConnection->query($this->query)) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $row["user_name"] . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you have to run `list_users()`:

```
<?php
include("users.php");

$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'testdb';

$myDB = new MyDB($host, $username, $password, $dbname); 
$myDB->list_users();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a million - that was it